# Why did Avraham prefer the daughters of Aner, Eshkol and Mamre over Eliezer's daughter?

Tags: gentiles, marriage, avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

Rashi on Bereishis [24:39](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219/showrashi/true#v39) says that

> Abraham said to [Eliezer] “My son is blessed, and you are cursed [Eliezer was a descendant of Canaan who had been cursed by Noah], and an accursed one cannot unite with a blessed one.”

And Rashi on Bereishis [24:8](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8219/showrashi/true#v8) says that if Eliezer does not find a suitable match from Avraham's father's house then

> take him a wife from the daughters of Aner, Eshkol, and Mamre

We know Aner, Eshkol and Mamre are canaanites from Bereishis [14:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8209/showrashi/true#v13) where it writes "Mamre the Amorite", and the Amorites come from Canaan as written in Bereishis [10:16](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8174/showrashi/true#v16)

So since Aner, Eshkol and Mamre are also descendents from Canaan who was cursed, why did Avraham prefer their daughter's over Eliezer's?

Comment: What about _Siftei Chakhamim_'s answer( _Ot Tav_ at _Bereshit_ 24:39)?

Comment: @TamirEvan, I haven't checked, but if it answers the question then by all means post it as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

[Daas Zekeinim Baalei Tosfiyos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=295) says that you have to say that Anair Eshkol and Mamrei were not from Canaan. However over here [Daas Zekeinim Baalei Tosfiyos](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=303) says they were from Cannan, however they were still better than Eliezer as they were not Avadim like him.

Comment: So is their a contradiction between the two comments?  And I don't understand how they couldn't be from Canaan when Mamre was an Amorite.

Comment: The second _Da'at Zeqenim Ba'alei ha-Tosafot_ gives the same answer as the [Siftei Chakhamim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&pgnum=305)( a couple of pages later) I mentioned [in comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23375/why-did-avraham-prefer-the-daughters-of-aner-eshkol-and-mamre-over-eliezers-da#comment54998_23375) to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps because G-d had already told Avraham that Eliezer would not inherit from him in [Bereishit 15:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8210#showrashi=true&v=4). Even though this was Eliezer's daughter and not Eliezer, perhaps Avraham felt that G-d's exclusion of Eliezer extended to his entire family as well.